# How to update updated_at field for a Sequel dataset?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am using Sequel gem to update a dataset.

If you do an update on the model instance, the updated_at timestamp gets updated just fine:

```
foo = Foo[id: 1]
foo.update(blah: blah)
```

However, when you call a batch update on the dataset, it does not update the updated_at timestamps for every entry.

`Foo.where(id: 1).update(blah: blah)`

I looked at the [Sequel docs regarding the timestamps plugin](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/Timestamps.html), which I am using in my code already, but the updated_at fields will still not be updated using the batch update. Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `Foo.where(id: 1).update(blah: blah)` executes a single query on the database, which is not going to run model instance-level hooks.  You can either update each record individually:

`Foo.where(id: 1).all{|f| f.update(blah: blah)}`

or you can switch to a database-trigger based approach, such as https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel_postgresql_triggers

Answer (score 0):

There's an update_all function you could look at. It's an active record method so it should trigger the updated_at.

Update: okay i just checked and it does not trigger, you should use his answer!